# sequence of jQuery deferred callbacks

Tags: javascript, jquery, deferred

If I have something like

```
var promise1 = $.ajax(...).done(callback1);
var promise2 = $.ajax(...).done(callback2);
$.when(promise1, promise2).done(callback3);
```

Is it guaranteed that `callback3` will run after `callback1` and `callback2`?  (the first two callbacks may run in either order, depending on the underlying AJAX completion.)

It appears to be the case in some limited testing, but is it always true or coincidence?  In other words, does `done` return a new promise that resolves when the callback is finished?

Comment: Yes, it guarantees that the third callback will only be called after both requests have finished, that's the whole point, and it's clearly stated in the documentation.

Comment: @adeneo: Is it stated? Notice those are `done`s, not `then`s. If you would do `promise1.done(callback4)` after the `$.when` call, it would not hold any more.

Comment: @Bergi - that's because then you would be doing `$.when(undefined, promise2).done(....` as the variable would not be defined ?

Comment: after adding a 4th callback to the done of promise1, it will fire 2nd if promise1 finishes first, or 4th if promise2 finishes first because the when added a done callback to the callback stack of promise1, then the 4th callback was added after that. http://jsfiddle.net/pQD4G/ http://jsfiddle.net/pQD4G/1/

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code in the OP. the third callback will always be run after callback 1 and 2 regardless of what other callbacks you later add to promise 1 and 2. It isn't possible for the $.when to resolve until after callback1 and callback2 are executed.

Comment: done does not return a new promise, .then does. However, it's rather useless unless teh callback is performing some kind of asynchronous action, in which case the callback would need to be passed to .then and the new promise object created inside the callback would need to be returned to the callback.

Comment: @adeneo: I meant `var promise1 = $.ajax, promise2 = $.Deferred().resolve(); $.when(promise1, promise2).done(callbackA); promise1.done(callbackB)`. Here the order of A vs B is undefined (you can hunt it down in the code of an implementation, but it's not specified anywhere).

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Callbacks (per single promise) are guaranteed to be run in the same order in which they are attached. At least the [spec dictates this for `then`](http://promisesaplus.com/), and while jQuery does not follow [all of] the spec [the `Callbacks` objects](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.Callbacks/) is implemented like this.

However, you should never need to rely on this. If `callback3` does depend on the results (actions) of the previous callbacks, it should state so explicitly. You can create promises for the results of callbacks with the [`then` method](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/) (formerly [`pipe`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.then/)):

```
$.when(
    $.ajax(…).then(callback1),
    $.ajax(…).then(callback2)
).done(callback3);

// more explicit:

var ajax1 = $.ajax(…),
    ajax2 = $.ajax(…),
    ajaxAndAction1 = ajax1.then(callback1),
    ajaxAndAction2 = ajax2.then(callback2),
    everything = $.when(ajaxAndAction1, ajaxAndAction2);
everything.done(callback3);
```

Comment: What's the difference between `done` and `then` - I thought `done` is just a special case of `then` that only has the success (done) callback?

Comment: That's what it used to be. Now it actually creates and returns a new promise object. (jQuery 1.8+)

Comment: yes, I do depend on the first 2 callbacks finishing before running the third callback.

Comment: Nope, `then` is the new [`pipe`](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe) (if you're accustomed to the old, nonstandard terms) :-)

Answer (score 0):

If `callback1` and `callback2` don't do any asynchronous actions (such as further ajax requests or animations,), you can use your code and be comfortable knowing that `callback1` and 2 will always be complete before `callback3` is executed using your existing code. However, if `callback1` and/or `callback2` perform further asynchronous actions, you need to use `.then` if you want to wait until the further asynchronous actions are complete too.

```
function callback1 (data) {
    return $.ajax(...);
}
function callback2 (data) {
    return $.ajax(...);
}
var promise1 = $.ajax(...).then(callback1);
var promise2 = $.ajax(...).then(callback2);
$.when(promise1,promise2).done(callback3);
```

Comment: Even when they are doing any synchronous actions one should use `then` when the third callback depends on their results.

Comment: if it's synchronous, their results will be available before the callback finishes executing, therefore it will be available when callback3 executes because the .when can't resolve until both callback1 and callback2 are done executing. As far as *should* but don't necessarily have to, i can agree with that.